# How can i reduce gap between legend and chart in highchart of type column where legend is aligned at top without reducing height of chart?

Tags: highcharts

```
legend: {
  enabled: legendVisible,
  symbolRadius : 0,
  verticalAlign: legendVerticalAlign,
  align : legendHorizontalAlign
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margin is the space between the legend and axis/chart

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.margin

```
    legend: {
  enabled: legendVisible,
  symbolRadius : 0,
  verticalAlign: legendVerticalAlign,
  align : legendHorizontalAlign,
  margin: 5
}
```

Comment: this margin is in pixel so how can i provide margin in % or in em ?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the space between the plot area and the legend, you can manually set chart `marginTop`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywxp6Lk5/

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 50
}
```

Or, you can adjust to your needs `margin` and `padding` legend properties: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5dxntqsy/

```
legend: {
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
}
```

Comment: this margin is in pixel so how can i provide margin in % or in em ?

Comment: Highcharts accepts only pixel unit, but you can convert other units to pixels, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/up1o4ce3/